# Excel worksheet compare two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two columns of data, I am trying to see if there is a match of anything in column b matches anything of column a.

I have tried a few if statements and a few vlookup statements -

`=if(B2=A3, "TRUE", "FALSE")` and `=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$B:$B,1,FALSE)))`

Comment: In C2: `=COUNTIF(A:A,B2)>0` Then copy down.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question is lacking details needed for anyone to be able to help you. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including the formulas you have so far. Otherwise, we may end up offering the same things you have already tried. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: =if(B2=A3, "TRUE", "FALSE")

Comment: =NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$B:$B,1,FALSE)))

Answer (score 0):

As [Scott](https://superuser.com/users/567231/scott-craner) said, you can catch matches with [countif](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)

So `=COUNTIF(A:A,B2)>0)` searches for B2 in A column and counts how many times it is found. Dragging it down will then do the same in B3, B4, etc.

This means if B2 is found more than once in column A it will return TRUE rather than the number of times it's found because of the test `>0`.

---

You can also use [match](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) to return the matching row.

```
=MATCH(B2,A:A,0)`
```

This will error if it's not found, so you can wrap it in `iferror`

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(B2,A:A,0),"No Matches")
```

Both of these require absolute matches, so any extra white space will not show a match. You can remove leading and trailing white spaces with [=TRIM()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388fa-c5df-49c6-b16c-9e5630b479f9).

Comment: I tried the first option =COUNTIF (A:A,B2)<0) and it worked on some of them but not on all.  Row two is a match, but It shows as false

Comment: too bad there wasn't a way to attach files, I could show you what I meant

Comment: Be sure you're using `>` not `<`. Also you need it to be an exact match, so if there are errant spaces or anything, you will need to use `TRIM()` to dispatch with those.

Comment: How does TRIM work